# Re-store SQL jobs from saved "create job code" in DR scenario?

Tags: sql-server, jobs

As DR and good practice, we [Backup] everything

We backup our SQL logins, jobs, linked server, system settings into a separate database so that we can restore it in DR scenario
The job was exported by PowerShell to local file, then read into DB table

Now to reverse above process [Restore]

We have the code to re-create logins, linked servers, from these tables right now, but I can't think of an easy way to re-create SQL jobs

**Can anyone suggest some ideas?**

### **Assumptions (DR scenario):**

- original server is down (so we cannot script out in SSMS)
- all we have is the DBA DB which contains the Backup* tables
- Entire job creation script is stored inside 1 table. To give an example, an instance has 27 SQL jobs, which got saved as CREATE script in DB as separate lines (1 line per row) = we have 3853 rows (max. column width is 862)

### **This is what I've thought so far**

- I don't think I can read entire 4000 rows and EXEC(@SQL) as that exceeds VARCHAR(MAX)
- search for each job (like rows between "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "EndSave:", store into @SQL and run it?
- export entire table back to disk file and run it?

Here are the some saved "CREATE JOB" code (stored exactly like this, with row # in front)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'syspolicy_purge_history', 
  @enabled=1, 
  @notify_level_eventlog=2, 
  @notify_level_email=0, 
  @notify_level_netsend=0, 
  @notify_level_page=0, 
  @delete_level=0, 
  @description=N'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 
  @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
  @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Verify that automation is enabled.', 
  @step_id=1, 
  @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
  @on_success_action=3, 
  @on_success_step_id=0, 
  @on_fail_action=1, 
  @on_fail_step_id=0, 
  @retry_attempts=0, 
  @retry_interval=0, 
  @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
  @command=N'IF (msdb.dbo.fn_syspolicy_is_automation_enabled() != 1)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR(34022, 16, 1)
        END', 
  @database_name=N'master', 
  @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Purge history.', 
  @step_id=2, 
  @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
  @on_success_action=3, 
  @on_success_step_id=0, 
  @on_fail_action=2, 
  @on_fail_step_id=0, 
  @retry_attempts=0, 
  @retry_interval=0, 
  @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
  @command=N'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_syspolicy_purge_history', 
  @database_name=N'master', 
  @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Erase Phantom System Health Records.', 
  @step_id=3, 
  @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
  @on_success_action=1, 
  @on_success_step_id=0, 
  @on_fail_action=2, 
  @on_fail_step_id=0, 
  @retry_attempts=0, 
  @retry_interval=0, 
  @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'PowerShell', 
  @command=N'if (''$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(INST))'' -eq ''MSSQLSERVER'') {$a = ''\DEFAULT''} ELSE {$a = ''''};
(Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))$a).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()', 
  @database_name=N'master', 
  @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'syspolicy_purge_history_schedule', 
  @enabled=1, 
  @freq_type=4, 
  @freq_interval=1, 
  @freq_subday_type=1, 
  @freq_subday_interval=0, 
  @freq_relative_interval=0, 
  @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
  @active_start_date=20080101, 
  @active_end_date=99991231, 
  @active_start_time=20000, 
  @active_end_time=235959, 
  @schedule_uid=N'3f7fa6aa-4768-4c67-bb2f-500926f03401'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:   GO  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You mentioned this, and definitely how I'd do it.... just export it out to a txt file, rename it a .sql file, and then run from there.

Comment: Have you considered backing up and restore the `msdb` database? That's where all the jobs are stored (along with some other stuff). Normally, this is the preferred DR approach, from what I've seen.

Comment: Yes, now I think of restoring MSDB as we'll have 1-to-1 VM in DR cloud (using Rubrik restore). Saving as text is not easy to automate

Comment: turns out Rubrik cannot restore MSDB as its 1st step to take it offline fails :( now we have to look at workarounds